# How to understand 无法可修饰的一对手

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics, hong-kong

The song [真的爱你](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1owuA0WkEw) begins with this line:

```
 无法可修饰的一对手
```

which means literally "A pair of hands that can't be decorated". It's his mother's hands so they might be aged a bit but I feel there must be more meaning here. The song is voiced in Cantonese but seems to be entirely Modern Standard Chinese.

What does the singer mean by 无法可修饰?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

无法可修饰的一对手 means "A pair of hands that can't be made smooth (to be beautified) again"

修饰 = polish --> make smooth and white --> to beautify

The mother in this song worked hand-laboring jobs for a long time that made her smooth female hands rough beyond help from beautification